# Calculating values that depend on the previous row

Tags: pandas

It seems that cumsum, cumprod and other cumulative operations can not be transformed. At present, it seems that the cumulative operation can only be done in a row-by-row cycle.

Data about 10 million lines, need to do cross-line calculation cycle, the computer can not run at all, consult the solution, thank you.
The calculations needed are as follows：

```
for i in range(1,10000000):
    df.iloc[i,3] = df.iloc[i-1,3]*df[i,1]+df[i,2]
```

Comment: Try `df.shift(-1).iloc[:,3]*df.iloc[:,1]+df.iloc[:,2]`

Comment: Thanks, but the answer is not right, next compute depend on the previous one, it's  recursive.

Comment: Oh, then you need an extending window function. Which will slow down the process. If you want correct answers it helps if you formulate your question in a way that it is obvious what you want. Please provide an example input and desired output!

Comment: Thaks, I tried np.array, it takes 3s.

Comment: As I said, please update your question with example input and output. That makes it way more attractive to post an answer and reduces the risk for getting wrong ones.

Answer (score 1):

There probably is no pythonic way to do it without looping it in C/Java style.

Added: Thus, just do a loop. Or hack using global variables etc as follow:

```
prev_result = 0
def my_func(x): 
    global prev_result
    prev_result = x.a * prev_result + x.b
    return prev_result
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [1, 2, 3]})
df["c"] = df.apply(my_func, axis=1)
# df["c"] is now [1, 4, 15]
# 0 x 1 + 1 = 1; 1 x 2 + 2 = 4; 4 x 3 + 3 = 15;
```

Edit: The followings are not cumulative and hence, does not answer the question.

That being said, @pythonic833 's solution:

```
df.shift(-1).iloc[:,3]*df.iloc[:,1]+df.iloc[:,2]
```

is quite a decent one.

If I were you, I'd just assign df["temp_column"] as df["third_column"].shift(-1)

```
df["temp_column"] = df["third_column"].shift(-1) 
df["third_column"] = df["temp_column"] * df["first_column"] + df["second_column"]
```

My proposed solution is a bit easier to read at the cost of memory for a column.

Comment: The answer is wrong, recursive compute, next compute depend on the previous one.